# How to iterate 1d NumPy array with index and value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, iterator

For python `dict`, I could use `iteritems()` to loop through key and value at the same time. But I cannot find such functionality for NumPy array. I have to manually track `idx` like this:

```
idx = 0 
for j in theta:
   some_function(idx,j,theta)
   idx += 1
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You can use `enumerate` for this.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22171558/what-does-enumerate-mean. Or iterate `range(len(theta))`.

Comment: Or better, `ndenumerate`  if you are dealing with NDarrays.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

There are a few alternatives. The below assumes you are iterating over a 1d NumPy array.

#### Iterate with [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range)

```
for j in range(theta.shape[0]):  # or range(len(theta))
   some_function(j, theta[j], theta)
```

Note this is [the only](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/3111) of the 3 solutions which will work with [`numba`](http://numba.pydata.org/). This is noteworthy since iterating over a NumPy array explicitly is usually only efficient when combined with `numba` or another means of pre-compilation.

#### Iterate with [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

```
for idx, j in enumerate(theta):
   some_function(idx, j, theta)
```

The most efficient of the 3 solutions for 1d arrays. See benchmarking below.

#### Iterate with [`np.ndenumerate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndenumerate.html)

```
for idx, j in np.ndenumerate(theta):
   some_function(idx[0], j, theta)
```

Notice the additional indexing step in `idx[0]`. This is necessary since the index (like `shape`) of a 1d NumPy array is given as a singleton tuple. For a 1d array, `np.ndenumerate` is inefficient; its benefits only show for multi-dimensional arrays.

#### Performance benchmarking

```
# Python 3.7, NumPy 1.14.3

np.random.seed(0)

arr = np.random.random(10**6)

def enumerater(arr):
    for index, value in enumerate(arr):
        index, value
        pass

def ranger(arr):
    for index in range(len(arr)):
        index, arr[index]
        pass

def ndenumerater(arr):
    for index, value in np.ndenumerate(arr):
        index[0], value
        pass

%timeit enumerater(arr)    # 131 ms
%timeit ranger(arr)        # 171 ms
%timeit ndenumerater(arr)  # 579 ms
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use `numpy.ndenumerate` for example

```
import numpy as np
test_array = np.arange(2, 3, 0.1)
for index, value in np.ndenumerate(test_array):
    print(index[0], value)
```

For more information refer to https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndenumerate.html

Comment: Also keep in mind that this is extensible to multiple dimensions.  index is a tuple containing the index of each dimension of the array.  Quite useful!