# How to extract elements in an array with regard to an index?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, subset

I have a row `A = [0 1 2 3 4]` and an index `I = [0 0 1 0 1]`. I would like to extract the elements in `A` indexed by `I`, i.e. `[2, 4]`.

**My attempt:**

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
index = np.array([0, 0, 1, 0, 1])
print(A[index])
```

The result is not as I expected:

```
[0 0 1 0 1]
```

Could you please elaborate on how to achieve my goal?

Comment: Check out the [documentation on boolean indexing](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterate over numpy with index (numpy equivalent of python enumerate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42082607/iterate-over-numpy-with-index-numpy-equivalent-of-python-enumerate)

Comment: Actually, @Quang Hoang's answer solves my problem efficiently ^^. I work with very large matrix, so I think the solution in the linked answer is not as efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want boolean indexing:

```
A[index.astype(bool)]
# array([2, 4])
```

Answer (score 0):

A non-numpy way to achieve this, in case its useful - it uses zip to combine each pair of elements, and returns the first if the second is true:

`[x[0] for x in zip(a, i) if x[1]]`